# joining of multiple files using Map Reduce

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

Join the contents of 2 files:

**First File** (Contains Employee Name Data)

```
id,name
101,Gaurav
102,Rohit
103,Karishma
104,Darshan
105,Divya
```

**Second File** (Contains Employee Department Data)

```
id,dept
101,Sales
102,Research
103,NMG
104,Admin
105,HR
```

==========================

**Output**

```
id,name,dept
101,Gaurav,Sales
102,Rohit,Research
103,Karishma,NMG
```

How do i acheive this kind of output ?

As of now i'm getting the out as random values in the reducer like..

I want the output in specified order like id,name,department.
Any help appreciated.

Mapper class looks like this...

```
public class JoinMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {
private Text keyEmit = new Text();
private Text valEmit = new Text();
public void map(LongWritable k, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException
{
 String line=value.toString();
 String[] words=line.split(",");
 keyEmit.set(words[0]);
 valEmit.set(words[1]);
 context.write(keyEmit, valEmit);
}
}
```

Reducer class looks like this...

```
public class JoinReducer extends Reducer<Text, Text, NullWritable, Text> {
String merge = "";
public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    merge = key.toString(); // 101
    for(Text value : values) {
        merge +=  "," + value.toString();
    }
    context.write(NullWritable.get(), new Text(merge));
}
}
```

Driver class looks like this...

```
public class JoinDriver {
public final static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    Job job = new Job(conf, "Multiple join");

    job.setJarByClass(JoinDriver.class);
    // job.setMapperClass(JoinMapper.class);
    job.setReducerClass(JoinReducer.class);

    MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]),
            TextInputFormat.class, JoinMapper.class);

    MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[1]),
            TextInputFormat.class, JoinMapper.class);

    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[2]));
    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
}
}
```

The output is as follows as of now, i want it like id, name, department in that order itself.

[image: output as of now]

Comment: You'll need to provide your code in your question.

Comment: @BinaryNerd please check the code, what i got to know is the the values which will be sent as input to reducer is random, how to make it sent in specific order in this specific case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem you have is that values aren't sorted, thus you're grouping on a common key but just sending the values as strings isn't massively helpful because you dont know which is the name and which is the department.

You have a few options, all of which require sending more information from the mapper:

1. Use a secondary sort
2. Sort the values in the reducer

The quickest a way to do this is append some more information to the value when you output it in the mapper (ideally you would actually use a composite value containing two Text objects).

```
public class JoinMapperName extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {
    public void map(LongWritable k, Text value, Context context) 
                          throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        String[] words = value.toString().split(",");
        context.write(new Text(words[0]), new Text("name:" + words[1]));
    }
}

public class JoinMapperDept extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {
    public void map(LongWritable k, Text value, Context context) 
                          throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        String[] words = value.toString().split(",");
        context.write(new Text(words[0]), new Text("dept:" + words[1]));
    }
}
```

So now you have a different mapper for each data source. And you need to change the reducer to something like:

```
public class JoinReducer extends Reducer<Text, Text, NullWritable, Text> {
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) 
              throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        String name = "";
        String dept = "";
        for(Text value : values) {
            if (value.toString().startsWith("name")) {
                name = value.toString().split(":")[1];
            } else {
                dept = value.toString().split(":")[1];
            }
        }
        String merge = key + "," name + "," + dept;
        context.write(NullWritable.get(), new Text(merge));
    }
}
```

This is just a quick example on how you could do it. Hopefully it gives you some ideas about how you can enforce ordering.